# Can I assign value to a variable among if condition on Python

Tags: python

I write my code that way, I want to assign matched values to 'm'
but lst[1] may not including the pat I want.
if it does, so I'll keep do something about 'm'
eg: m.group(2).split() ....

```
  if re.match(pat, lst[1]):
       m=re.match(pat, lst[1])
```

But I don't want to repeat the re.match(pat, lst[1]) twice.

I want to achieve in that way

```
  if m = re.match(pat, lst[i])
```

but it shows me "invalid syntax error.
any ideas?

Comment: In fact, I think you want to DRY (not repeat) yourself ;)

Comment: its like asking for using braces instead of indentation in Python

Comment: @ThePhysicist that's exactly what I thought when I read it.  As it currently stands, OP is saying he doesn't want to not repeat himself, or equivalently that he does wish to repeat himself.

Comment: Why is this even a problem? If you just do `m = re.match(pat, lst[i])` then `m` will be `None` if there are no matches; you can completely get rid of the `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign the value beforehand and check if it's None:

```
m = re.match(pat,lst[1])
if not m:
  del m
```

Comment: Thank you~ I forgot your solution

Comment: You're welcome! Coming from Ruby I'm sometimes tempted to use `unless (a = ...) do` syntax as well, which sadly (or luckily!?) does not work in Python...

Comment: ha I love Ruby , but not familiar enough

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse `for` for your task.

```
def for_if(expression):
    if expression:
        yield expression

for m in for_if(re.match(pat, lst[1])):
    # work with m
```

or just

```
for m in (i for i in (re.match(pat, lst[1]),) if i):
    # do the same
```

This is not really helpful for readability, but is the only way to combine assignment and test.